# Insert YouTube Comment reply using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create a program using Google Apps Script that inserts a reply to a given youtube comment with its ID. But when I try to insert a comment, it throws an error,

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.commentThreads.insert
> failed with error: Comments cannot be empty. startCommentThread   @
> Code.gs:42

Line 42: `YouTube.CommentThreads.insert(resource, "snippet");`

Here's my code:

```
function startCommentThread(vid,ytch, fc) {
  var fc,vid,ytch
  fc ="Hi" //This is reply comment
  vid ="3a8VpwZm2Kw" //This is video id
  ytch ="UCNXOZLBWDbLJxxXcLEpKzVQ" // channel id
  const resource = {
        snippet: {
          channelId: ytch,
          videoId: vid,
          textOriginal : fc,
          parentId : "UgyvUFY31md_zpE9eqV4AaABAg" //comment id
                  }
                    }
YouTube.CommentThreads.insert(resource, "snippet");}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) seems to indicate that the structure of your request body is incorrect.

Based on the documentation, I think the request body should look like this:

```
const resource = {
  snippet: {
    channelId: ytch,
    videoId: vid,
    topLevelComment: {
      snippet: {
        textOriginal: fc
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT**
I see now that you want to simply insert a reply to an existing thread. I noticed in your code you were attempting to call YouTube.CommentThreads.insert, so I assumed the goal was to create a new thread.

If you're only looking to reply to an existing thread, and you already know what the ID of that thread is, you can structure your resource like this:

```
const resource = {
  snippet: {
    textOriginal: fc,
    parentId: threadId // whatever the ID of the parent thread is.
  }
};
```

You'd then call YouTube.Comments.insert, rather than YouTube.CommentThreads.insert.

Comment: But I need to insert comment reply

Comment: @NivedPadikkal Based on the documentation, I believe the textOriginal property is what will be listed as the visible comment of the newly created thread.

Comment: How insert an reply

Comment: @NivedPadikkal What you'll get back from the successful CommentThreads.insert call is an object that represents the newly created thread. That will contain an id property that you can use to make another call to Comments.insert. You'd pass the id from the comment thread as the parentId of the comment you are creating. This should create a reply.

Comment: In this structure where I put parentId

Comment: @NivedPadikkal I've made an update to the answer that should help answer your question.